# модуль DearPyGui. Из-за чего не ставится шрифт?

Tags: python, gui, шрифты, dearpygui

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

dpg.create_context()

with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font(r"fonts\consolas.ttf", 18, default_font=True):
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)

with dpg.window(tag="Primary Window"):
    dpg.add_text("тест")

dpg.create_viewport(title='TEST', width=600, height=200)
dpg.setup_dearpygui()
dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.set_primary_window("Primary Window", True)
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

[image: output]

Comment: Видимо в consolas.ttf нет кириллицы.

Comment: @СергейШ consolas предназначен для стандартной командной строки windows 10 и имеет кириллицу

Comment: @СергейШ сменил на lucida console - не помогло

Comment: https://geekrepos.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/1674 последний код

Comment: @СергейШ geekrepos - это зеркало github.com. Лучше прямую ссылку давать: https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/1674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("./LiteralRegular.otf", 20, default_font=True, tag="Default font") as f:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
```

Если не ошибаюсь, сам шрифт скачивал [здесь](https://webfonts.pro/base-web-fonts/sans-serif-grotesque/1079-literal.html)

В конце также добавил

```
 dpg.bind_font("Default font") # эту строчку
 dpg.set_primary_window(window='main_wind', value=True)

 dpg.setup_dearpygui()
 dpg.show_viewport()
....
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваш ответ!